# django model many to many not working with charfield as primary key

Tags: mysql, django, database, model, many-to-many

I'm trying to accomplish a many to many relationship between my models where one table has a charfield as a primary key.
The manage.py makemigrations works just fine, but running manage.py migrate crashes with:

```
django.db.utils.OperationalError: (3780, "Referencing column 'articleCategory_id' and referenced column 'ArticleCategory_id' in foreign key constraint 'item_overview_articl_articleCategory_id_da76142b_fk_item_over' are incompatible.")
```

Here is model 1:

```
class Advertisement(models.Model):
    advertisement_id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    advertisement_startDate = models.DateTimeField()
    advertisement_endDate = models.DateTimeField()
    advertisement_isDefault = models.BooleanField()
    advertisement_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='banners/')
    advertisement_categories = models.ManyToManyField(ArticleCategory, related_name='ArticleAdvertisements')
```

and model 2

```
class ArticleCategory(models.Model):
    ArticleCategory_id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
    ArticleCategory_value = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    ArticleCategory_parent = models.ForeignKey("self", on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=True)
    ArticleCategory_type = models.ForeignKey(ArticleType, on_delete=models.PROTECT, null=False)
```

Thanks in advance for the help! I've been stuck in this for way to long now :)

Comment: This is a bug with Django already having a ticket [#32743](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/32743)

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I've been strugelling on this way to long :)